# log4j - lo4j shell-vulnerability

Tags: java, logging, log4j

For the lo4j vulnerability, I have removed log4j-1.2.8.jar, log4j-1.2.17.jar and log4j-core-2.1.jar files and added reload4j.jar and log4j-core-2.17.1.jar in my application.

I use the Ant build script to generate the application jar file, while building the application I am getting an error message - error: **package org.apache.logging.log4j does not exist** and **import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;**

I have the below jar files in my lib path but still, I am getting an error message
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.1
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6
slf4j-api-2.1
slf4j-api-1.6.6
log4j-api-2.17.1
log4j-core-2.17.1
reload4j

I have read an article that reload4j is a drop-in replacement for log4j 1.x so I replaced the log4j 1.x with reload4j.

Please help me how to fix this error.

Comment: If you're getting an error while building, then it indicates that the required JAR (`log4j-api`) is not on your compile-time classpath. Which may be different from the deployed application's classpath. Unfortunately, you don't provide any information about what's actually happening, just what you think that you've done.

Comment: Also, Log4J 2.x has a "bridge" JAR that will implement the Log4J 1.x API. I would use that instead of `reload4j`. See https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html